# Cloudy whiteish looking spot on my finish - what happened?

Tags: finishing, random-orbit-sander

Have a weird spot on a walnut headboard I was hoping that someone could help me with. See the picture below. There is a cloudy whiteish looking spot in the middle of the headboard. It only shows if the light hits it just right. Im wondering what when wrong and how to prevent it next time. Also, is there anything I can do now?

I finished the headboard in watco Danish oil natural color and before that sanded through the grits 80 - 120 - 220 with a random orbit sander. After sanding, I wiped the Danish Oil on as directed on the can. In between coats, I sanded lightly by hand with 600 grit wet/dry paper.

[image]

Comment: i would sand it again and apply another coat.  looks like you brushed it w/ your sleeve or knee or something.

Comment: Danish oil is very forgiving.  It looks like you have a spot that somehow needs more sanding work.  I would sand that portion, then put on more Watco.  Since you are using natural coloring without added coloring, you won't have problems with matching the new coat or coats to what is already there.

Comment: It's hard to tell from just one photo what has gone on here (more angles would help) but I agree with both of the above Comments. It's lucky you used "Danish oil" as it is very forgiving and you can easily top up or reapply. You can either wet-sand that spot with 600 paper (lubricated with the finish) or just sand, wipe clean and then rub in some new finish, feathering out to the surrounding area.

Answer (score 1):

It could be glue. It ends up in some strange places. I would thoroughly sand the area to bare wood and reapply the finish. I recently had a spot show up in the middle of a board. Just my 2 cents.